# How can I use pgf from within TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Background: I understand that Ti*k*Z is built on top of pgf. Both are described in the pgf manual. However, I have been unable to find the section (if it exists at all) of the manual describing how the two are connected. This is a problem to me, as I enjoy the high level constructs of Ti*k*Z, yet I notice a number of useful primitives in pgf that I don't know how to access.

As an example, consider this simple picture:

[image: two line segments and the intersection of their extensions]

There are two short, non-intersecting line segments. The circle marks the point where the extended lines meet. The line segments and node labels were created with Ti*k*Z, the intersection with pgf.

Here is the code, lifted from the manual and adapted slightly:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=20mm,y=20mm]
  \draw
  (.5,0) node[left](A){$A$} -- (1,.8) node[left]{B}
  (2,0) node[left](C){$C$} -- (1.5,1) node[right](D){D};
  \pgfpathcircle{%
    \pgfpointintersectionoflines
      {\pgfpointxy{.5}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{1}{.8}}
      {\pgfpointxy{2}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{1.5}{1}}}
    {2pt}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, the code is not DRY: The coordinates are repeated in the pgf section. But if the points A–D were them selves the result of calculations, this is not a viable option. Also, I can *draw* the intersection point, but I cannot *use* it in further work at the Ti*k*Z level. Hence my questions:

> - How do I represent the points A–D in terms that `\pgfpointintersectionoflines` and other pgf constructs can use?
> - And how do I extract the result from the pgf world, for further use in the Ti*k*Z world?

Note that I am looking for answers that can be generalised, not a hack applying only to the present problem.

Comment: For the second part, seems you can do e.g. `\pgfcoordinate{foo}{ \pgfpointintersectionoflines
      {\pgfpointxy{.5}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{1}{.8}}
      {\pgfpointxy{2}{0}}{\pgfpointxy{1.5}{1}}}` to get a coordinate named `foo` at the intersection.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed, that works. Thanks! (To be clear, it can then be referred to as `(foo)` later on.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to what Torbjørn T. says you can use existing nodes/coordinates with `\pgfpointanchor{<name>}{<anchor>}`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=20mm,y=20mm]
  \draw
  (.5,0) node[left](A){$A$} -- (1,.8) node[left](B){B}
  (2,0) node[left](C){$C$} -- (1.5,1) node[right](D){D};  
   \pgfcoordinate{aux}{\pgfpointintersectionoflines
      {\pgfpointanchor{A}{east}}{\pgfpointanchor{B}{east}}
      {\pgfpointanchor{C}{east}}{\pgfpointanchor{D}{west}}}
   \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointanchor{aux}{center}}{2pt}
  \pgfusepath{stroke}
  \draw (aux) -- (aux|-A.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. But I had just realised, before seeing your answer, that I messed up a little: I should have let `(A)` refer to coordinates, not anchors. I.e., I should have used `(.5,0) coordinate(A) node{$A$}` and similarly for the other points. And then, all the `\pgfpointanchor` macros can be given `{center}` as their second argument.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen You haven't "messed up" I think.;-)

Answer (score 1):

I did come up with another solution myself. It is not as nice as marmot's answer, but as it is a different approach to the same problem, possibly enabling a different set of options, I offer it here, for the record:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=20mm,y=20mm]
  \draw
  (.5,0) coordinate(A) node[left]{$A$} -- (1,.8) coordinate(B) node[left]{B}
  (2,0) coordinate(C) node[left]{$C$} -- (1.5,1) coordinate(D) node[right]{D};
  \tikzmath{
    coordinate \A; \A = (A);
    coordinate \B; \B = (B);
    coordinate \C; \C = (C);
    coordinate \D; \D = (D); }
  \pgfcoordinate{E}{
    \pgfpointintersectionoflines
      {\pgfpoint{\Ax}{\Ay}}{\pgfpoint{\Bx}{\By}}
      {\pgfpoint{\Cx}{\Cy}}{\pgfpoint{\Dx}{\Dy}}}
  \draw (E) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the process of getting there, I learned the difference between `\pgfpoint` (canvas coordinates?) and `\pgfpointxy` (user coordinates).

Comment: I *knew* you would go for `\tikzmath` ;-)